# Getting 502 error when using spring integration provided by aws-serverless-java-container

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Below is my handler class. I expect simple string body as response. But i am getting 502 errors. Is this issue with Spring not returning string responses or serveless container emulation issue. I have gone through the code, its executes dispatcher service method directly after creating http request object from aws lambda invoke context.

{
  "statusCode": 502,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "body": "{\"message\":\"Gateway timeout\"}",
  "base64Encoded": false
}

```
public class MyHandler implements RequestHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> {

public static SpringLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;


public MyHandler() throws ContainerInitializationException {
        handler = SpringLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(SpringConfig.class);
}

public AwsProxyResponse handleRequest(AwsProxyRequest input, Context context) {
    System.out.println("Servlet context Before = " + handler.getServletContext());
    AwsProxyResponse resp = null;
    try {
       resp  =  handler.proxy(input, context);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       context.getLogger().log("Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Servlet context After = " + handler.getServletContext());
    System.out.println("Response = " + resp.getBody() + " statusCode=" + resp.getStatusCode()
    + " resp=" + resp.getHeaders());
    return resp;
}
```

}

Here is my controller

```
@Controller
```

public class MyController {

```
@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;

@RequestMapping(value="/sampleApp.jnlp")
public String home(HttpServletRequest request){
    System.out.println("ServletContext " + servletContext);
    System.out.println("Ctr : Request : " +request);
    //System.out.println("Ctr : response : " +response);
    return "\"key1\":\"value1\"";
}
```

}

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: I dont remember now. But it was something to do with api gateway integration configuration. Can you out more details about your problem code snippet? command used (curl) to test it? If you have not enabled cloud watch logs I suggest turn it on and log your response before returninng. You will have to add cloud watch access level in your lambda exec role to have cloud watch logs populated